# Unexpected omission by Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries, diophantine-equations

When Alpha is submitted the equation $a(a^2-1)=2b^2$, it unexpectedly forgets the integer solution $a=1,b=0$. What could explain this ?

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(a%5E2-1)%3D2b%5E2

Comment: Workaround, putt to Wolfram Alfa: `solve a*(a^2-1)=2*b^2, a>=0,b>=0, for integers`, see last solution?

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk: thanks for the suggestion, but my question is more about why it is so.

Comment: It really didn't forget this answer, it's right there in a>=1, b= answer, and there in the graph (where the curve on the right hits the x axis). It just isn't flagged as an integer answer. You can find it with FindInstance[a (a^2 - 1) == 2 b^2, {a, b}, Integers, 3]

Comment: @bills: I don't want to tell Alpha how many solutions or what signs to find. I want to understand why it didn't report all of them. Otherwise my trust will decrease.

Comment: @bills: I can't imagine how the solution could be missing on the plot. But undisputably, the solution $a=1,b=0$ is missing in the "Integer Solutions" sections, and this is worrisome.

Comment: FWIW alpha calls `Reduce[a (a^2 - 1) == 2 b^2, {a, b}, Integers]` and extracts out the explicit integer roots listed there. `Reduce` can't find all solutions and the solution you seek is lumped into the redundant part of the output.

Comment: I don't think it makes sense to ever trust a computer algebra system. It is a tool, and it can sometimes do amazing things, but it is certainly not without its quirks. Check and double check everything!

Comment: When `Reduce` fails completely, alpha has a numerical algorithm that tries to guess roots. This algorithm would have caught your root but wasn't called since `Reduce` gave us an answer. I'll file a bug internally to get this fixed on the alpha side of things.

Comment: Also note that `Reduce[a (a^2 - 1) == 2 b^2, {b, a}, Integers]` returns the root in question.

Comment: @ChipHurst: thank you for this insight. Note that the Reduce syntax you supplied seems to be interpreted the right way (solve *over the integers*), but no integer solution is returned by Alpha (instead, expression of $a$ in terms of $b$).

Comment: The result leaves much to be desired but it is technically not wrong. It asserts that the solution is integers a and b such that b equals the messy right hand sides. This is true of all integer solutions of this equation. If I had to guess, `Reduce` didn’t know how to solve as a Diophantine equation and so it just performed cylindrical decomposition and tacked on the assertion that a and b are integers. This is better than coming back I evaluated I think. And the explicit solutions are probably the boundaries of the CAD which is why they appear. Again, just a guess.

Comment: @bills: after several years of usage, this is the first time I see a result that cannot be explained (I have seen several Mathematics posts claiming Alpha mistakes, but in all cases Alpha was right and the output was misinterpreted by the posters). IMO, Mathematica is more reliable than most humans.

Comment: ["Some kinds of questions are considered off-topic: Questions on Wolfram Alpha (but questions on using Wolfram Alpha within Mathematica are okay)..."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @MichaelE2: then my question is off-topic, as I don't have Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

I have observed that the anomaly disappears when the resolution is explicitly asked over the integers (the qualifier Diophantine also works).

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(a%5E2-1)%3D2b%5E2+over+the+integers

So it seems that the flaw would be in the logics for the "Integer solutions" section that comes along with an unspecified domain (presumably $\mathbb C$ by default). As suggested by @chiphurst, this could be because a general solver is used and might fail to find the exact integers.